# Replace part of URL during mouse hover to get original size image

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey, userscripts

For Violentmonkey or Greasemonkey.

I want to replace part of a URL during *mouse hover*, so that I could copy to memory the original size of the image instead of the provided one. The image URL patterns are constant. The desired texts to be replaced are always on the same locations, perhaps like a template.

Example of a blogspot.com page:

https://hopedogrescue.blogspot.com/2019/06/what-you-need-to-know-about-canine.html

Example of an image URL from the above page:

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-k-J3eJs1nH0/XQg9ZTO9i2I/AAAAAAAAVXI/MJijXqZxrLQt9xmoK-mHlAJPrtFe7SM4ACLcBGAs/s1600/matthieu%2Bserious.jpg

Example of the image URL from above, now s1600 is changed to s0 :

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-k-J3eJs1nH0/XQg9ZTO9i2I/AAAAAAAAVXI/MJijXqZxrLQt9xmoK-mHlAJPrtFe7SM4ACLcBGAs/s0/matthieu%2Bserious.jpg

If I am in a forum or whatever page, I want whatever existing image posted there by a User as it was. I want the URL for the image's original size during mouse hover, so that I could save internet data. My downloader will intercept the image's URL from memory when copied. Hence, I could repeatedly revisit the forum/page with its existing images as they were.

So far, the s1600 is not changed to s0 during mouse hover.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        My orig image sizes
// @description Get orig image sizes.
// @namespace   My monkey scripts
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// @match       *://*.blogspot.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https:\/\/.\.bp.blogspot.com\/.\/.\/.\/.\/s1600\/.\.jpg'
  url = url.replace('s1600','s0')
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that, when you hover over the dog picture on the blogspot page, you want the link that will be copied (or navigated to) if you "Copy link location" to show s0 instead of 1600? It's not entirely clear to me

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think he means to replace the image url when the mouse is over it. Am I right @Wankilya?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, so that I could copy the original "s0" url of the image to memory (instead of the provided "s1600") which would be detected/intercepted by my downloader. Thus I would save internet data, because the webpage's images are still what they originally are. Thanks.

Comment: @k3llydev Yes, ditto. Thanks.

Comment: Why only replace while the mouse is over it, rather than permanently? Wouldn't that be a lot easier?

Comment: @CertainPerformance For example, if there are many images on a page or forum with the provided size of "s200"... those are small sizes as ease which is good. But I want to right-click the image and instead to get the original/biggest size of "s0" to memory which would be detected/intercepted by my downloader. Thus the page or forum is still "s200", thus save internet data.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this by DOM references, which is actually how JavaScript works when it has to modify or reference the DOM.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let imagesData = [];

images.forEach((i,x)=>{
  imagesData.push(i.src); //Saves every DOM reference of an img tag
  i.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{toggleImage(x,true);});
  i.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>{toggleImage(x,false);});
});

function toggleImage(e,h) {
  images[e].src = h ? "//placehold.it/150/00F/FFF/?text=Hover" : imagesData[e];
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="//placehold.it/150/600/FFF/?text=Image 1">
<img id="img2" src="//placehold.it/150/A00/FFF/?text=Image 2">
<img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/150/F00/FFF/?text=Image 3">
<img id="img4" src="//placehold.it/150/C00/FFF/?text=Image 4">
```

> **Note**: If you want to replace a specific url depending on the previous one, you can get it with `images[e].src` inside toggleImage function.

Comment: I've been trial-and-erroring. How to put regex in `images[e].src`? In your example above of `/150/00F/FFF/`, how can I replace 150, 00F, and FFF with regex, so that they would accept any other values (just like asterisks (*) for CMD)? Thanks.

Comment: @Wankilya What do you actually want to do? Obtain and replace `150, 00F n FFF`? Obtain only? Replace only? What I mean with my note was that the original URL would always be inside `images[e].src`.